# Identifying a resistor

Tags: resistors

As a newbie I am trying to a resistor's rating - the top most one in the photo (R12).

Would you concur that the 2nd and 3rd bands are black, and not brown? Without any experience I am erring between the two.

[image: resistor]

If I understand correctly the difference between black and brown is significant - 20 ohms (black) and 210 ohms (brown). If it helps this is a board from a channel of a power amplifier.

The replacement I have found to buy is "1 Watt Carbon Film" - should this be sufficient. Are there any other factors I need to consider?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why replace it? That one looks fine. If another one burned and this one is the same, measure it to be sure.

Comment: They *appear* black to me, but monitors can be tricky so measuring it is the only way to be sure.  In-circuit measurement can give varying results depending on what else is attached to the resistor, but will give a LOWER bound to its value.  Those look a little small to be 1W resistors.  However, without the schematic, we can't tell what the power rating should be.

Comment: I think R12 is brown, black, black, gold, which means 10 ohms with 5% tolerance. You seem to think the first band is red? But red is much more red, like in the other resistor, that's clearly brown, black, red, gold.

Comment: The problem with eyes and photographs is the lighting spectral content may be lacking some Red from white LEDs.  So there can be a saturation difference.  The other problem is the Hue of Brown is usually the same as Red, just different saturation and Luminance which means Red is subdued and B/G rise until all are equal then it's grey. for RGB a middle brown is  128 64 64 and this Red in question ranges from 161-47-36 to 202-38-39 in the middle while the other resistor is even higher red and 1st band closer to brown.  So if we're wrong, check it with a meter and then consider why replace it.

Comment: Using Photoshop Elements to correct the color based on areas believed to be black, gray and white, R12 and the one just below and to the right appear to be red - black - black and red - black - orange. I think brown may be more like gold as in the smaller resistor below and to the right.

Comment: The photo shows the good channel, the other channel's resistor is burnt/charred so I am using the good channel to identify. I didn't realise I could simply measure with a multimeter. On the lowest setting (20ohms) I got a reading of 11.0. The reading is initially higher then settles around 11.

Comment: But 11 ohms and the colours I have identified do not tally with any of the calculators that I am checking against.

Answer (score 0):

I just checked again with a torch and the correct colours of the bands are:

brown / black / black

The phot was taken with a flash on a phone which made the brown appear as red. The other resistor in the photo which appears orange is in fact red when viewed with a torch.

So this would conclude that this is a 10 ohms resistor.

Thanks for being patient with me, I leanred a few things here today.